# Why am I unable to acces external javascript files using codeigniter even though they get loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

My project is using a combination of Bootstrap and Codeigniter. I cannot access functions within external javascript files. Using firebug in Firefox I can see that these external scripts get loaded.  External css files work fine. Please note that jquery works but I suspect that it is because of the jquery.js file that is included in the Bootstrap/Codeigniter framework in directory assets/js/jquery.js

Here is my header code within every Codeigniter View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/icons/favicon.png">

    <title>Sample Website</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- styles custom to our site -->
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>   

</head>
```

Comment: You have only `3` `jQuery` files and you mentioned `jQuery` works then what else ?

Comment: Between `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` ?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>-->` is this a typo ?

Comment: yeah its a typo entering it into the question box...I removed it

Comment: the css and Jquery works but not the JQuery UI and the jquery cookie...I have experimented with another external javascript file but it will only work if i copy the file's contents into the current page

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: remove jquery.cookie.js and than check if it is working or not

Comment: is this on localhost? if not, are you using https? if yes let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add base_url before url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url();?>js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```